# Moving to the selected row in the HTML table when the table has scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a table and I am using the selected property of the row when the user clicks on the row in the table. In other panel I have a map and it has all the employees displayed on it. Each row in the table has unique ID and when the user clicks on the employee image on the map that employee row in the table gets highlighted. Now if the table has 40 rows I have vertical scrollbar shown. When I click on the employee with Id 40 the row in the table gets selected but the row is not shown in the view because the table has scrollbar and it is hidden by the scrollbar. The following is my html code:

```
<div class="customTable">
    <table class="table" id="employeesTable">
        <thead class="active">
            <tr>
                <th>employee ID</th>
                <th>employee State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <div>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees ng-class="{'selected':employee.empId == selectedRow}"  id="row{{employee.empId}}" "  style="cursor: pointer">
                    <td>{{employee.empId}}</a></td>
                    <td><span>{{employee.employeeState}}</span></td>                                                
                </tr>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now When I click on a employee image on the map the following code is called:

```
$scope.employeeDisplay = function(employee){
            //to display employee in the table
            //called when the employee is clicked on the map
            var id = employee.empId;
            $('#employeesTable tr').eq(1).removeClass('selected');
            $scope.selectedRow = empId //so based on the employee is that particular row is highlighted in the table
        }
```

Could you let me know how the table could automatically display the selected row if the row is not in the initial view, like the table shows only 20 rows and if the employee with id 40 is selected the table should scroll to the selected row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSFiddle that has the basic behavior you're looking for. All it does is scroll to the 40th element if it is not already in view.

https://jsfiddle.net/reid_horton/odd0omk7/1/

It works by setting the `scrollTop` property of the scrollbar element to the `offsetTop` property of the item you want to view, thus scrolling the scrollbar to the point where the element is at the top of the viewport.

To check if the item is already in view, it compares the current position of the scrollbar to the position of the element. It then uses the height of the viewport to determine if the element is in a viewable range of values.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="scrolling-container">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="k in items">
        <td>{{ k }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- As an example, scroll to the 40th element -->
  <button ng-click="scrollItemIntoView()">
    Scroll to Bottom
  </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {

  // Populate the table with 0..100
  $scope.items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.items.push(i);
  }

  // This function is called when the button is clicked.
  $scope.scrollItemIntoView = function() {

    var scrollElement = $('.scrolling-container')[0];
    var itemToView = $('tr')[40];

    // This is where it all goes down.
    if (!itemIsInViewport(itemToView)) {
      scrollElement.scrollTop = itemToView.offsetTop;
    }

    // Determines if the item is already in view.
    function itemIsInViewport(item) {
      var $scrollElement = $('.scrolling-container');
      var upperBound = item.offsetTop;
      var lowerBound = item.offsetTop - $scrollElement.innerHeight();
      var currentPosition = $scrollElement.scrollTop();
      return lowerBound < currentPosition && currentPosition < upperBound;
    }

  }

});
```